# Key Mapping to Switch Keyboard Language?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, language-bar

Is there any way to make a specific key combination switch the keyboard language?

I would like to be able to switch from Russian keyboard to English keyboard with a key combination instead of having to bring up the language bar every time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a standard key-shortcut to switch between languages. For me it is set at <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but you can change it.

Go to your keyboard settings and click the last tab (`Advanced Key Settings`). There you can set your key-shortcut to switch `Between input languages`.

[image: Language switch]